# Response is not sent to postman from springboot controller

Tags: spring-boot, postman

I am receiving my response back in the controller from service class. But the response is not received in the postman. Postman shows 500 internal server error.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/data/employeeDetail", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,  produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<EmployeeDTO> getEmployeeDetails(@RequestBody EmployeeInformationDTO employeeInformationDTO ) throws Exception {
        
        try {
                
            EmployeeDTO employeeInformation = (EmployeeDTO) employeeOnboardingService.getEmployeeDetails(employeeInformationDTO);
            return new ResponseEntity<EmployeeDTO>(employeeInformation, HttpStatus.OK);
                
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        
    }
```

I am able to print the information from the **employeeInformation** object. But the response is not returned back to the postman from the return statement.

There are no errors printed in the console as well.

Kindly guide me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you mention your Controller class definition ? Along with annotations used?

Comment: which version of spring boot are you using?